# Set Chart as Agent's Icon

Tags: anylogic

I want to create an agent that will process some data and show it on chart.
I want the chart to be the icon of the agent so when I put the agent in a sapce it will appear as the chart, where i placed the agent (Just like you would place a regular chart).
Couldn't find any solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not what "Icons" are made for. Use the default approach:

1. ensure your chart has "show on embedded agent" enabled
2. embed the agent into some parent agent (or main)
3. Click on the agent or agent population
4. in the properties, click the "show presentation" button

this will plot the agent presentation that includes the chart. You can drag it anywhere, independent of the actual agent icon.

Comment: Worked! I'm a bit ashamed because I have tried to play with those properties and coudn't make it work. And then it is so simple. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is a bit confusing at first, but extremely powerful once mastered :)